# How to allow my Visio drawing inside a web part to occupy the whole upper area, as currently I will get an empty upper area

Tags: web-part, page-layout, visio, visio-services

I have a Visio drawing with .vdw , then I used the Visio Web Access web part to add the drawing to my wiki page. I set the following settings for the web part:-

[image]

But I will get a free upper area as shown in he below picture:-

[image]

Now I can move the mouse on the drawing and drag it to start from the upper area,, but of course I need this change to be permanent,, so can anyone advice on this please

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is the visio drawing that is the problem, not the webpart. Check the margins/size/borders in your visio drawing.

Comment: @user19952 i though the same way at first. but i have modified the visio drawing to fully occupy the page inside the visio software.but still i will get the same problem. so there is no way to add additional components inside the current visio drawing because it fully occupied the drawing ... so i think it is the web part problem,, what di u think?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue... The solution was that i had a text box that i had rotated and the area of the text box went into the area above the drawing - even though there was no text in that area at all!!

Under the Home tab, there is a box that looks like it's rotating... that is Text Block (Shift+Ctrl+4) and with that you can click on the boxes to see the size they actually reserve for text.